# Sometimes broken scrolling in Emacs while using the touchpad

Tags: scrolling

I am usually able to scroll in Emacs using both, scrolling with the keyboard keys and scrolling using the touchpad.

In order to achieve smooth scrolling line by line with a point in the center line of the window I had put following code:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<down>")
  (lambda (&optional ARG TRY-VSCROLL) 
    (interactive "^p\nP")
    (next-line ARG TRY-VSCROLL) 
    (recenter)))
(global-set-key (kbd "<up>")   
  (lambda (&optional ARG TRY-VSCROLL) 
    (interactive "^p\nP") 
    (previous-line ARG TRY-VSCROLL) 
    (recenter)))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<up>")   'previous-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<down>") 'next-line)
```

into my Emacs initialization file.

After I have done this above I have witnessed weird Emacs behavior while using touchpad for scrolling and assumed that the change in the initialization configuration is the reason for the issue because going back to standard key bindings didn't brake the touchpad scrolling.

Observed weird behavior of touchpad scrolling ranged from switching the focus to the minibuffer to switching between the tabs in the tab bar instead of scrolling.

Because of the question in the comment by *@Drew* I had while testing the touchpad scrolling also switched the focus away from Emacs to another applications (Firefox and xed) to test if there is an impact on touchpad scrolling behavior while using applications outside of Emacs.

What now totally confuses me is that after coming back with focus to Emacs the touchpad scrolled the text properly also in Emacs.

---

UPDATE because of currently not being able to reproduce the described issue:

After the tests mentioned above and coming back with focus to Emacs I have now no idea how to reproduce the described weird behavior of the touchpad scrolling in Emacs and what could be the actual condition resulting in witnessed weird touchpad scrolling behavior.

Hmmmm ... are not reproducible bugs actual bugs? I terms of conditions to fulfill for a bug report not reproducible bugs are not bugs ...

After four weeks of Emacs, it appears to me that Emacs is not only a text editor or as some say a kind of an Operating System, but also an adventure with many surprising (one-time) experiences.

I will keep this question here as a report of a witnessed issue and eventually come back to it after being able to track it down to its core and give instructions how to reproduce it.

Comment: Are you saying that setting some Emacs key bindings somehow affects something outside Emacs (e.g. your touchpad scrolling, in general)? Or are you saying that touchpad scrolling is lost only when using Emacs?

Comment: @Drew : after some testing because of your question I had to totally rewrite my question. In other words your question had the side-effect of solving the issue ... at least until the issue occurs again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why this answer?

There is currently not possible to reproduce the issue, so the answer is here for the purpose of marking the question answered only.